# an exception is occurred while play an audio in blackberry

Tags: blackberry, java-me

```
try {
    Player p = javax.microedition.media.Manager.createPlayer("abc.mp3");
    p.realize();
    VolumeControl volume = (VolumeControl)p.getControl("VolumeControl");
    volume.setLevel(30);
    p.prefetch();
    p.start();
} catch(MediaException me) {
    Dialog.alert(me.toString());
} catch(IOException ioe) {
    Dialog.alert(ioe.toString());
}
```

I used above code to play an audio in blackberry. But it gives an exception error as mentioned in below.

```
javax.microedition.media.MediaException
```

Comment: Is there a more specific exception message? It is usually something like this: `java.network.TimeOutException: timeout too long`?

Comment: on creating your player, give the proper location of the source file.

Answer (score 4):

If you look at the [BlackBerry API docs](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/javax/microedition/media/Manager.html#createPlayer%28java.lang.String%29), you see that for the version of `createPlayer()` that you use:

> MediaException - Thrown if a Player cannot be created for the given locator.

It also says:

> locator - A locator string in URI syntax that describes the media content.

Your locator (`"abc.mp3"`) doesn't look like it's in URI syntax.  You could try changing that, to something like `"file:///SDCard/some-folder/abc.mp3"`.

Or, if the mp3 file is an app resource, I usually use this code:

```java
    try {
        java.io.InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/sounds/abc.mp3");
        javax.microedition.media.Player p =
            javax.microedition.media.Manager.createPlayer(is, "audio/mpeg");
        p.realize();
        // get volume control for player and set volume to max
        VolumeControl vc = (VolumeControl) p.getControl("VolumeControl");
        if (vc != null) {
            vc.setLevel(100);
        }
        // the player can start with the smallest latency
        p.prefetch();
        // non-blocking start
        p.start();
    } catch (javax.microedition.media.MediaException me) {
        // do something?
    } catch (java.io.IOException ioe) {
        // do something?
    } catch (java.lang.NullPointerException npe) {
        // this happened on Tours without mp3 bugfix
    }
```